# What kind of RF-splitter does the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 use, and what type is the PCB-Antenna below?

Tags: rf, identification, raspberry-pi, pcb-antenna

There's a version of the Compute Module 4 available, with on-board WLAN.
The RF-out min of the RF module goes through what seems to be a splitter, and then into both a U.FL- (UMCC)-type connector, but also into a co-planar PCB antenna:

[image: Raspberry Pi CM4 (detail)]
*(The arrow points to the RF-splitter, the dashed line is around the PCB-antenna)*

Now I have two questions:

1. What kind of RF-splitter IC are they using? The CM4 schematics aren't available, unfortunatelly, so I can't check myself. But I definitely want to know what kind of splitter they use and what sort of impedance matching happens right at the IC.
2. The planar antenna looks quite interesting. Can someone tell me the name of that antenna type? I've seen a bunch of IFA, ILA, BIFA, etc. antennas used for WLAN in the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz ranges, but never this kind of corner antenna, that seems to be quite wideband. Also, the caps used in it are quite interesting, if someone could point me to more information about the antenna setup, that'd be great.

As I said above, if the schematics were available, I'd check myself, but they're not available for the CM4, and the markings on the RF-splitter are nondescript ("K").

Comment: What you're calling an "RF-splitter" is more likely an RF switch. Code in the microcontroller can command it to connect to either the internal antenna, or the external antenna connector.

Comment: I'd consider that antenna a broadband slot antenna.

Comment: Theres an article about the antenna design here: https://www.antenna-theory.com/design/raspberry-pi-antenna.php

Comment: @Linkyyy nailed it with that article! It's a kind of Vivaldi / tapered slot antenna.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt OK, the RF-switch actually makes more sense, now that I think about it. I was thinking perhaps they're using some sort of RF power splitter, but I've only seen those in their own RF cages mostly with SMA or N connectors. Never as an individual chip. Can you perhaps point me to the one the CM4 uses, i.e. the part number of it? (In case you know, or have some idea what it *might* be, etc.

Comment: @Linkyyy thanks! It's exactly what I needed. I've only seen Vivaldi antennae with rounded elements, never a trapezoid like this one.